# How to calculate daily weekly monthly price change in percentage?

Tags: historical-trade-data, binance, math

I am trying to match the binance's daily price change. I know it does provide 24h price change in percentage but the value I calculate is off no matter what.

So I am asking binance API to give me candle data for 1 day/week/month respectively.

I have these values I am using: current price (P), open price (OP), close price (CP).

I tried these but the values do not match what binance is showing for the daily change so I know all other calculations are also wrong:

```
priceChangeInPercentage = 100*(P - OP)/P
```

How does binance calculate this value?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the denominator to Open Price (OP) because the 24hpercentage will be calculated on basis of OP not on the last traded price (P).

```
priceChangeInPercentage = 100*(P - OP)/OP
```

Comment: Dropping from $6,000 to $3,000 is not a 100% drop. :)

Comment: Yes, it's not a 100% drop.
OP=6000$
P=3000$

change%= 100*(3000-6000)/6000 = -50%